# AMP - custom font doesn't loaded in CDN url

Tags: css, magento, fonts, font-face, amp-html

I embedded a custom font inside the tag `<style amp-custom>` like this

```
@font-face{
    font-family:font-icon;
    src: 
    url('https://example.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/plumrocket/pramp/icon.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

This works properly when i'm viewing the site via `?amp=1` but when I use the cdn url `cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/example.com` the font doesn't get loaded.

When I check the full url in source code it became `/r/s/example.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/plumrocket/pramp/icon.ttf` which I believe is correct because the fonts should be treated as resources.

I tried to access the full cdn url of the font and it returns 404.

Ex: https://example-com.cdn.ampproject.org/r/s/example.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/plumrocket/pramp/icon.ttf

But when I change `r/s` to `c/s` the font returns 200 which is weird because `c/s` should be for documents.

Any idea why AMP treat my font as document and not as resources?

Update:

I was able to fix this issue, i just move my font file inside `skin/frontend/base/default/css/icon.ttf` to `skin/frontend/base/default/fonts/icon.tff`.

I believe that AMP read the file directory to determine if the file is a `content` or `resources` when caching it to the CDN url and since my third party module put the font file inside a directory with `css/` then AMP interpret it as a content.

Comment: Try to pattern your syntax in [documentation of amp](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/design/responsive/custom_fonts) if you haven't done so.

Answer (score 0):

Try your module to create such a function

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * Retrieve view url without cdn url
 * @param  string $file
 * @param  array  $params
 * @return string
 */
public function getAmpSkinUrl($file = null, array $params = array())
{
    $url = $this->getViewFileUrl($file, $params);
    $fontInfo = parse_url($url);
    $baseInfo = parse_url($this->getUrl());
    $url = str_replace($fontInfo['host'], $baseInfo['host'], $url);

    return $url;
}
```

In your case, you need to write something like this

```
@font-face{
font-family:font-icon;
src: 
url('<?php echo $this->getAmpSkinUrl('css/plumrocket/pramp/icon.ttf', array('_secure'=>true)); ?>') format('truetype');}
```

Comment: Hi, we are using getSkinUrl in the main code but in my example i use the full path just to be more clearer

Comment: Updated the answer, try this.